# what is the Prime factorisation of 28!

Tags: proof-verification, prime-factorization

Can someone check my solution for this question?

$28! = 2^a \times 3^b \times 5^c \times 7^d \times 11^e \times 13^f \times 17^g \times 19^h \times 23^i$

To find a:

$28/2 = 14$

$28/2^2 = 7$

$28/2^3 = 3$

$28/2^4 = 1$

Where $a= 14+7+3+1= 25$ giving $2^{25}$

I repeated this method to find b to i to give a final answer of

$28! = 2^{25} \times 3^{13} \times 5^6 \times 7^4 \times 11^2 \times 13^2 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23$

Is this method/answer correct?

Comment: Yes, to find the power of a prime $p$ in $n!$ just compute $\sum_k\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\rfloor$. What you are doing is counting how many divisors of $p$ are there which contributes with a $p^1$, then you look at the mutiples of $p^2$ which contributes one more $p^1$, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct and your method is fine, but not your choice of notation. It is *not* true that $\dfrac{28}{2^3}=3$. You are interested in integer division here, and therefore what you should write is $\left\lfloor\dfrac{28}{2^3}\right\rfloor=3$.